# Storing Linq results in a pre-defined List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a defined class -

```
class Adjustments
    {
        public int AdjustmentID;
        public int AdjustmentTypeID;    
    }

class AdjustmentsList
    {
        public List<Adjustments> items = new List<Adjustments>();        
    }
```

if i do a query such as this:

```
var Day0Spot =
                (from a in a1
                 join fx in q
                     on a.CurrencyCodeID equals fx.CurrencyCodeID
                 select new
                 {
                     a.AdjustmentID,
                     a.AdjustmentTypeID
}).ToList();
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to make Day0Spot be of type AdjustmentsList.
The end goal of all of this add Day0Spot (and a few other similar lists) to an item of AdjustmentsList (let us call it MasterList) via some mechanism (looks like concat would get me there).

edit - i suppose i could use for each and loop through Day0Spot and manually add to MasterList, but that just seems silly

Comment: In case anyone comes across D-shih's answer helped.  In the 'select new' part of the query you can specify the type so 'select new Adjustments' was key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can try this.

Create `Adjustments` object and fill data on it in linq,then use new a `AdjustmentsList` object to carry the List.

```
var Day0Spot = (from a in a1
                 join fx in q
                     on a.CurrencyCodeID equals fx.CurrencyCodeID
                 select new Adjustments()
                 {
                     AdjustmentID = a.AdjustmentID,
                     AdjustmentTypeID = a.AdjustmentTypeID
                 }).ToList();

AdjustmentsList adjustList =new AdjustmentsList(){
    items = Day0Spot
};
```

Comment: my actual class has a bit more members but getting a conversion error  - 
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int AdjustmentID, int AdjustmentTypeID, int FvDetailID, int Majorminor, int OffsetMajorMinor, string Description, int ChangeID, int Period, int Year, double Amount, int CurrencyCodeID, string EntryDate, string YYYYMM, double PY>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CalculationEngine.Classes.Adjustments>' CalculationEngine

Comment: though the ordering, type and names are all the same

Comment: Could you show us the `a1` and  `q` collection code?

Comment: A1 is of type adjustmentslist

Comment: that no sense If a1 isn't a collection,because linq need to use from collection,Have you add `select new Adjustments()` on the linq?

Comment: You are right I am sorry. It is an adjustmentslist.items

Comment: OK @user1272386 Here is a sample for you wish can help you 
 http://rextester.com/VCJLT60212